# SQL syntax error on WHERE clause using apache Derby

Tags: java, sql, derby

**For the following  SQL select statement ; -**

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT SS100.ORDERS.ORDER_ID, SS100.ORDERS.ORDER_NUMBER," +" SS100.ORDERS.PERSON_ID, SS100.PERSON.FIRST_NAME"+
"FROM  PERSON, ORDERS " +
"WHERE SS100.PERSON.PERSON_ID = SS100.ORDERS.PERSON_ID " );
```

**I'm getting  a syntax error on the WHERE  keyword -  dump as follows :-**

```
 java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "WHERE" at line 1, column 126.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at Database.orderQuery(Database.java:146)
    at MainApp.main(MainApp.java:19)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error: Encountered "WHERE" at line 1, column 126.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)... 10 more
```

I've tried playing around with the alias statement, but then get an error on the '.' dot operator. I'm obviously doing something fundamentally wrong but I can't see it at the moment, can anyone help?

Comment: Check the SQL you generate here. If you print it to the console, you'll notice, that you are missing a space before the `FROM`.

Comment: You are missing a space before `FROM`

Comment: thanks guys, you're absolutely right, that sorted out the problem, now I've just got to sort out the rest!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here:

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT ..." +... + " SS100.ORDERS.PERSON_ID, SS100.PERSON.FIRST_NAME"+
    "FROM  PERSON, ORDERS " +
```

There's no space between `"SS100.PERSON.FIRST_NAME"` and `"FROM"`.

This can be easily solved by always starting your parts with an space:

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT ..." +... + " SS100.ORDERS.PERSON_ID, SS100.PERSON.FIRST_NAME"+
    " FROM  PERSON, ORDERS " +
    " WHERE ..."
```

Comment: Hi Luiggi, as per the above, problem sorted, and thank you for your excellent suggestion as to starting parts with a space, I will be doing this from now on!!

Comment: @MartinClifford you're welcome. If you find this answer as the most useful for your problem, please mark the green check below the rep :).

Comment: Hi Luiggi, I'm sorry, I don't understand 'green check below'  what's that all about?

Answer (score 0):

This concatenation of strings will turn into

```
"SELECT SS100.ORDERS.ORDER_ID, SS100.ORDERS.ORDER_NUMBER," +" SS100.ORDERS.PERSON_ID, SS100.PERSON.FIRST_NAME"+
```

"FROM  PERSON, ORDERS " +
"WHERE SS100.PERSON.PERSON_ID = SS100.ORDERS.PERSON_ID "

```
SELECT SS100.ORDERS.ORDER_ID, SS100.ORDERS.ORDER_NUMBER, SS100.ORDERS.PERSON_ID,
SS100.PERSON.FIRST_NAMEFROM  PERSON, ORDERS WHERE SS100.PERSON.PERSON_ID =
SS100.ORDERS.PERSON_ID
```

The issue is where `FIRST_NAME` and `FROM` join. Add a space after `FIRST_NAME` and the sql should run fine.

However, you should really be asking yourself why you are doing this. If you know the values to concatenate, why not have one string to start with.

Comment: Hi Ash, the space was the problem, which I have now sorted, thanks. However I don't understand your last comment about concatenate and one string, could you explain?